# How to Create a survey from Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Google Spreadsheet and Google Form to create a Survey. There are ten questions, need two different sites'(A, B) people to answer, if people come from A site, need to answer question 1. 2. 4. 6. 7. 8. 10, and if people come from B, need to answer question 1. 2. 3. 6. 7. 8. 9. 10, the order of the questions couldn't be change, must from 1 to 10. What should I do? How could I complete this Survey. 
I have to create the first question, and based on that answer, go to different page. So there are three pages, the first is the first question page, the second is the Site A question page, and the third is the Site B question page. based on the first page's answer to go to different page. 
But there is a question, because there are some of the same questions between Site A and Site B (1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10). So when I submit the answer, there are some repeat questions column about the same questions in spreadsheet, that's not what I want.Thanks for help!

Comment: I really hope that somebody could help me solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: One day past, still no people could help me.

Answer (score 0):

SO may not be the best place for this question, as it is more of a usage issue instead of a google apps script question.  You might have more luck over on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

That being said, I'm not sure that there's a way to get around the fact that both page's questions appear on one spreadsheet.  You could try to prefix the questions with an "A." or "B." possibly.

Is there any reason why you couldn't use a dedicated survey for each site instead of one for both?  I haven't tested it, but you may be able to use the "Choose Response Destination" option under the "Responses" menu of the form and record the form responses to different sheets in the same workbook.